# error code 1 on pip install pysha3, merkletools

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I've been trying to install pysha3 and merkletools for the blockcerts cert-issuer quickstart, but I keep getting essentially the same type 1 error when I try to pip install.

I read on a separate post that I should try upgrading setup tools

```
pip install --upgrade setup tools
```

and install ez_setup

```
pip install ez_setup
```

Both of these worked, and pip install also worked when I ran "pip install pyethereum," but I still keep getting the same error codes when I try to install pysha and merkletools.
For "pip install pysha3" I get the error:

> Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-install-tvsl7vp1/pysha3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-record-n8e9n_dm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-install-tvsl7vp1/pysha3/

For `pip install merkletools==1.0.3` I get:

> Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-install-m87p6nra/pysha3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-record-b8x3lh7l/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/pip-install-m87p6nra/pysha3/

It looks like the pip that's being called when I run `pip install` and `pip --version` are two separate things. When I run `pip --version` it says

> pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

but when I run `python -m pip install pysha3` it says

> You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

When I run `pip install --upgrade pip` I get the message

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (10.0.1)

Where should pip be installed so that I don't run into this error of different pips being called?

Comment: Have you tried using pip3?
Update: I just run with: ```python -m pip install pysha3``` and it worked.

Comment: @FábioCorreia on running `pip3 install pysha3` I still get essentially the same error (too long for a comment). `python -m pip install pysha3` failed with a similar error as well. All errors similarly say "failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q0/h9rx8b3s14g_33ng9xz31ykw0000gn/T/" with either a pip-build or pip-install directory after /T/.

Comment: Which version of pip you have installed?

Comment: `pip --version` =  pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: Ok, try this:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip (This will upgrade pip as a module of your global python)

python -m pip install pysha3 (This will try to install pysha3 into your global python).

note: If you are using Windows, always execute your terminal as admin. If not on Windows, it is not necessary using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Check, that the system (x32 or x64) you use and installed python version are proper for that system.